# Laptop stuck in airplane mode

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

Fresh install of windows 10 home. I can't get the laptop out of airplane mode. Any option is grayed out.

I can enable the WiFi and even see ssids for a second, then it goes back to disabled. I plugged in a USB wifi dongle and same result. It sees the USB dongle and adds it but I can't enable it in network options.

I plugged in an Ethernet dongle, that connects to Internet just fine.  did a full update but that hasn't changed the behavior.

I'm out of ideas at this point any help is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does [6 Ways to Fix Windows 10 Stuck in Airplane Mode](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-stuck-in-airplane-mode-fix/) answer your question?

Comment: Try as @David suggested and then update fully. Today is Patch Tuesday.

Comment: I had gone through the list but just did it a second time and got a bit different result. After disabling the radio management service I was able to enable wifi and Bluetooth. However... Airplane mode is still on. I refurbish these laptops for refugees so I'd like to turn that off. Laptops with non standard things like this may confuse the recipient as I don't service them after they are distributed

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-10-stuck-in-airplane-mode

Careful when editing registry

Answer (score 0):

It got ugly, But I think I got it fixed.

I disabled radio management service and this got me to be able to enable to enable wifi and bt. But the icon in the taskbar and airplane mode in settings were both on. Functional, but not acceptable.

I downloaded the Dell driver package which updated the BIOS. This tanked my windows install and I couldn't get it to boot without BSOD.

After reinstall of windows from scratch it seems to be working fine. Note: simply reinstalling windows before bios update did not fix this issue